# How to detect end of user input when using input method editors?

Tags: javascript, events, input, keycode, ime

For a project I'm using an iframe in design mode for user input. Because of different requirements I need to detect the end of the user input in order to retrieve the text that the user has entered.

Up till now I was just using an array containing all pressed key codes (added on key down and removed on key up) and as soon as the array got empty I knew that the input was finished. Using the cursor offset before and after the input I could retrieve the inputed text.

But then there were special characters and input method editors that have completely obscure event patterns depending on browser and operating system.

Just a few examples:

If you want to type "â" on OS X 10.10 using Chrome you get

- down 229
- up 192
- down 229
- up 65

Even worse on OS X 10.10 you could just hold "a" key down and then select "â" character from the menu. Giving you

- down 65
- press 97
- repeat down 65
- up 65
- down 50
- up 50

You could also just select the "â" from the menu by the mouse triggering no key events at all.

If you want to type "â" on Linux using Firefox you get

- up 0
- down 65
- up 65

Same using Chrome on Linux gets you

- up 192
- down 65
- press 226
- up 65

If you want to type "â" on Windows using Firefox you get

- down 160
- up 160
- down 65
- press 0
- up 65

Using input method editors complicates things even more.

If you want to type hex code "123" using Chrome and KDE on Linux (Ctrl+Shift+u 1 2 3 followed by a space) gets you

- down 17
- down 16
- down 229
- up 85
- down 229
- up 49
- down 229
- up 50
- down 229
- up 51
- down 229
- up 32

Same on Windows (Alt + 1 2 3) gets you

- down 18
- up 18
- up 107
- down 107
- press 0
- up 107
- down 39
- press 39
- up 39
- down 39
- press 39
- up 39
- down 18
- down 107
- press 0
- up 107
- down 35
- press 35
- up 35
- down 40
- press 40
- up 40
- down 34
- press 34
- up 34
- up 18
- press 0

These are just a few examples of how the events are differing depending on browser and operating system. Initially I thought about the key code 229 having a special meaning and being used for this kind of input which was also supported by different researches I did. But then during further testing and as you can see from my examples this is not true and not all browsers are using it.

After that I don't know how it should be possible to recognize the start and end of user input. I can't work using timeouts as to much can happen in between (e.g. user might change cursor position).

Actually I don't care about what was entered by the user based on the events as I retrieve it from the text as long as I know the start and end. But again the end seems not to be detectable as there is no clear "end key code sequence" or behaviour.

Can anybody point me to any information that might enable me to detect the start and end of user input properly?